# typescript refuses to transpile one file in a folder containing 3 TS files (using Visual Studio Code)

Tags: typescript, tsc

I have 3 TS files in a folder called util immediately below the root of my project.
i.e:

```
  +   .vscode
  +   src
  +   util
  +   dist
  -   package.json
  -   tsconfig.json
```

(not all files and folder shown)

In the util folder are 3 files:

```
AsyncFs.ts
AsyncQueue.ts
Now.ts
```

My tsconfig file is:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "sourceMap":true,
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "allowJs": true,
      "lib": [
        "dom",
        "dom.iterable",
        "esnext"
      ],
    },
    "include": [
      "src/**/*",
      "tests/**/*.ts",
      "routes/**/*.ts",
      "util/**/*.ts,"
    ],
    "exclude":[
      "node_modules",
      "bin"
    ]
  }
```

After running tsc, the dist folder will have a util folder under it but the util folder will only contain AsyncQueue.js, AsyncQueue.js.map, Now.js and Now.js.map.

The file AsyncFs.ts has not been transpiled! Why?

If I put AsyncFs.ts in another folder, say, src, it is transpiled! Why?

Comment: Any errors when running `tsc` ? What's in `AsyncFs.ts` ?

Comment: @Evert - no errors. it transpiles correctly when placed in a different folder

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found out why. But I can't explain why any of the files were transpiled!

If you look at the tsconfig "include: section, the line for util is

```
"util/**/*.ts,"
```

The comma is **inside** the quotes. The comma is not a special character in regular expressions, is it? If not then none of my files should match "*.ts,"